# Insert for multiple users

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to combine an insert with a select?
e.g.

Insert

```
INSERT INTO user_history VALUES (SEQ_USER_HISTORY_ID.nextval, '65567','AccountStatus', 'Y', 'N', sysdate, 1, 'Update');
```

Select

```
SELECT USER_ID FROM USER WHERE COUNTRY = 'MEX'
```

The select statement will return many user id's and I need an insert statement for each of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. To use it inline, the select has to be complete and has to return only one row.

For example

```
INSERT INTO user_history 
VALUES (select SEQ_USER_HISTORY_ID.nextval from dual, 
        '65567',
        'AccountStatus',
        'Y',
        'N',
        sysdate,
        1,
        'Update');
```

To use another SQL like `SELECT USER_ID FROM USER WHERE COUNTRY = 'MEX'` and insert multiple rows (one for each row in the SQL), you need to use it this way:

```
INSERT INTO user_history 
    (select SEQ_USER_HISTORY_ID.nextval,  
            USER_ID , 
            'accountStatus',
            'Y',
            'N',
            sysdate, 
            1,
            'update' 
     FROM USER 
     WHERE COUNTRY = 'MEX');
```

Reference (see the example section): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm#sthref1704

Comment: Sorry if not explained properly, I am trying to add a where clause to the insert statement.

Comment: Thanks Nivas. Worked a charm